# django admin with websocket

Tags: django, django-admin, django-channels

I am new to django. I want my admin panel to automatically update itself whenever new model instances are created without refreshing the page. I found that this can be implemented using websocket(django channels), But I do not know how to do with the django admin. Any help/suggestions/directions are much appreciated!!

Comment: A basic implementation would require you to add some custom JS to your admin page: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/admin/javascript/ then you can look at using this lib (that depends on Django Channels)  https://github.com/hishnash/djangochannelsrestframework to subscribe to an instance. You will need to handle this subscription in your JS and update the admin UI.

Answer (score 0):

You can use django signals `post_save` and `channel_layer` to send send the websocket request to the users and use custom javascript to refresh the page

Ref:

- [1] https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/signals/#post-save
- [2] https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/channel_layers.html#using-outside-of-consumers